# Read an XML file from a batch program

Tags: xml, batch-file

Good Morning,

I been searching the web and I can find anything that addresses exactly what I am trying to do.  I have this XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
  <header>
    <listname>Nintendo GameCube</listname>
    <lastlistupdate>09/26/2017</lastlistupdate>
    <listversion>SupraKarma1.1</listversion>
  </header>
  <game name="007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)" index="true" image="0">
    <description>007: Agent Under Fire (USA)</description>
    <cloneof />
    <crc />
    <manufacturer>EA Games</manufacturer>
    <year>2002</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <rating>ESRB - T (Teen)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
  </game>
  <game name="007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)" index="" image="">
    <description>007: Everything or Nothing (USA)</description>
    <cloneof />
    <crc />
    <manufacturer>EA Games</manufacturer>
    <year>2004</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <rating>ESRB - T (Teen)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
  </game>
</menu>
```

I need to read it from a batch file.  I thought I could use a vb script but for reasons, I won't get into I can't so I am back to a batch program.  I want to have it search for a file like "007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)" and have it return what the rating is for the game -ESRB - T (Teen) - into a variable.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Better add sample output...

Comment: Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell all have native capability to read and write XML.  Why wouldn't you use one of those?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you can supposedly use [`xpath.bat` from GitHUB](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) to retrieve the node with an XPath like this:

```
//game[contains(@name,"007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)")]
```

So if you want to call it from a batch file, use something like

```
call xpath.bat [parameters]
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get that into a variable then?

Comment: and How do I tell it I want the rating returned?

Comment: Not using VBScript would extend to not using WSH in general, wouldn't it, @DKalsow?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you leverage `PowerShell` from your batch file for this type of task:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "name=007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)"
Set "file=filename.xml"
Set "want=rating"
Set "variable="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('PowerShell -C "$xml=[xml](GC '%file%');"^
 "$xml.menu.game | ? {$_.name -eq '%name:'=''%'} |"^
 "Select -ExpandProperty %want%"') Do Set "variable=%%A"
If Defined variable Echo %variable%
Pause
```

Comment: The for the suggestion.  this power shell solution works get except when the name has an apostrophe in it like - Luigi's Mansion (USA).  Any ides how I can fix that?

Comment: The usual method of maintaining a single quote within a string is to escape that single quote with another. I have therefore made a change to the code in order to cater for such a case. Please feel free to check to see if it works given your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Windows batch file solution for this task:

```
@echo off
set "GameNameFound="
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims==<>" %%I in ('type "C:\Temp\Test.xml" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:"007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)" /C:"<rating>" 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%I" == "game name" (
        set "GameNameFound=1"
    ) else if defined GameNameFound (
        set "Rating=%%J"
        set "GameNameFound="
        goto HaveRating
    )
)
set "GameNameFound="
echo Could not find rating for game "007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)".
goto :EOF

:HaveRating
echo Rating for game "007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)" is: %Rating%
```

Command **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
type "C:\Temp\Test.xml" | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:"007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)" /C:"<rating>" 2>nul
```

This command line outputs with command **TYPE** the content of file `C:\Temp\Test.xml` to handle **STDOUT** which is redirected with `|` to input handle of **STDIN** of command **FINDSTR** which searches literally and case-sensitive for the strings `007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)` and `<rating>`. **FINDSTR** outputs all lines containing either first or second string. So for your example are output the lines:

```
    <rating>ESRB - T (Teen)</rating>
  <game name="007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)" index="" image="">
    <rating>ESRB - T (Teen)</rating>
```

Those lines are captured by command **FOR** and processed now line by line.

Because of `delims==<>` each line is split up into multiple substrings (tokens) using equal sign and angle brackets as string delimiters. `tokens=2,3` tells **FOR** that second substring of a processed line should be assigned to specified loop variable `I` and third substring should be assigned to next loop variable `J` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). All other substrings like the spaces/tabs left to opening tags (first substring) and remaining rest of each line are of no interest.

The first line `<rating>ESRB - T (Teen)</rating>` is ignored because the environment variable `GameNameFound` is not defined yet.

The second processed line is the line with the game name found by **FINDSTR** on which starting tag `game` and attribute `name` are assigned to loop variable `I` with the space between. So environment variable `GameNameFound` is defined now with any value. It does not matter which value is assigned to the environment variable.

The third line is expected to be the `rating` line of interest and its third substring assigned to loop variable `J` is the rating value of interest. For that reason this string value is assigned to environment variable `Rating` and the **FOR** loop is exited with a jump to label `HaveRating` for further processing it.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `type /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `|` and `2>nul`. The redirection operators `|` and `>` must be both escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.